# Website working on localhost but not on server

Tags: http

I have created a website it was working perfectly on localhost` not when I uploaded it.

It gives `HTTP 500 error`
I checked in the log it says

> Wed, 09 May 2018 20:46:30 -0500 AH00128: File does not exist: /home/vol4_1/byethost7.com/b7_22060877/htdocs/favicon.ico

I don't have anything like `favicon.ico`, I do not understand where this error is coming from

This is code, On all page's head

```
    `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$url?>/css/cosmo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$url?>/css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.9/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5SOiIsAziJl6AWe0HWRKTXlfcSHKmYV4RBF18PPJ173Kzn7jzMyFuTtk8JA7QQG1" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?=$url?>/img/Fav.png">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
```

Comment: Pretty self explanatory then ...

Answer (score 0):

The favicon.ico is the icon that appears next to the title on the browser tab.

Can you post the code please, so that we can see what you have

Comment: Try removing the '<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?=$url?>/img/Fav.png">' from the header

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a line in your head of your page reverencing to favicon.ico? 

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">`

If so you could try to remove it and check if the problem is solved.

Comment: No, i dont hav "Favicon.ico", I have "Favicon.png".

Comment: So there you have the problem, a Favicon can't be a .PNG it has to be an .ico. By inserting the code to ask for a Favicon.ico and not having one generates an error. On this site you can convert any jpg or PNG to an favicon.ico. http://icoconvert.com

Comment: Thanks great help! Working